# How can I list data and create a summary table?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010

Let's assume I have a table with sports results somehow like this:

```
player A | player B | 2 | 1 | player C | player D
player C | player B | 1 | 2 | player E | player A
```

As shown in table, there are any random players playing in a pair against another random pair.

What would be the most structural and logical way to get an output like this:

```
name     | games | wins
player A | 2     | 2
player B | 2     | 1
player C | 2     | 0
etc.
```

Currently I have tried working with `VLOOKUP`, but those formulas have been terribly messy and problem also arise because of the reason that the same player can be in "position 1" for one game and "position 2" for another...

Would love to see some opinion how to do this the best. I am rather new with this kind of "data-output" thing in Excel, as has been working with Math formulas mostly.

Comment: Can you explain the meaning of the numbers in the first table and how you get from those numbers to the numbers in the second table?  I seem to be missing it.  Also, what are the scoring rules for individual vs. team wins? (how do the numbers translate from pair to individual?)  Is partner information relevant?

Comment: First table numbers are just score. Goals for example. There cannot be ties. It just says "player A together with player B won against player C together wit player D with score 2 against 1".  And there are no individual or team wins, it is simple really - if you win, you win. Partner doesn't matter really.

Comment: Can you provide some feedback on whether the answer solved the problem or if not, clarify what is different in what you need?

Comment: If I'm understanding your question, the two helper columns do the comparison.  That form (i.e., C2>D2) evaluates to True or False (if C2 is GT D2, the expression is True), and those are handled for math purposes as 1 and 0, respectively.  So each helper column shows the wins for that team.  What the formulas do is search down each player column for the designated player and sum the wins in the helper column for that side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one solution.  Lets say the column headings in your first table are: Player1, Player2, LScore, RScore, Player3, Player4.  The data range for this example is A2:F100.  Your second table has every player pre-listed, and the names start in I2 and go down the column (I2="player A").  The objective is to fill in the game and win counts.

The game counts are easy.  For player A, the formula in J2 is:

```
    =COUNTIF($A$2:$F$100,I2)
```

Copy the formula down column J for all of the players.

The simplest way to do the wins is not very elegent, but it works.  You add two columns where you "code" the winner in countable form.  Column G will code the wins for the left team.  In G2:

```
    =(C2>D2)
```

Copy that down column G for the whole data range.  If the left score is higher than the right score, this will be True, which will get handled as 1 in calculations.  Otherwise, False will be handled as 0.  Column H will be the wins for the right team.  In H2:

```
    =1-G2
```

Copy this down column H.

The wins will be the combination of four sums, one for each position a player can be in.  So K2 will be:

```
     =SUMIF($A$2:$A$100,I2,$G2:$G100)+SUMIF($B$2:$B$100,I2,$G2:$G100)+SUMIF($E$2:$E$100,I2,$H2:$H100)+SUMIF($F$2:$F$100,I2,$H2:$H100)
```

Copy this down column K for all the players.

If you want this to be expandable, pre-populate columns G and H with an arbitrarily large number of entries, but add an IF test for each G and H entry to make the value zero if there is no data.  So for example, G2 and H2 would be:

```
    =IF(ISBLANK(A2),0,C2>D2)  
    =IF(ISBLANK(A2),0,1-G2)
```